# Loading a file from VS Code into node with integrated terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I'm attempting to load a JavaScript file I've created into the integrated terminal, so that I can check/mess around with variables/constants. I've tried "require"ing and "load"ing the file, but that just seems to execute what is in the file, as opposed to giving my access.

When I used Ruby, for example, I could open up Pry REPL and then type "load './filename.rb" and it would give me access to all of the variables and methods. I'd assume there would be an easy way to do so with node, since it is a REPL as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when you require a file, you essentially execute it and get the exported object as return value, if your exported object has callables, you can call them, if it has variables you can change them.

Essentially something as follows:

```
//A.js
module.exports = {add:(a,b)=>{return a+b}, b:2}


// Integrated terminal
let exportedStuff = require('A.js')
exportedStuff.add(1,2)
```